# What should I do to use a more recent jQuery version?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this [jQuery Bubble script plugin](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/07/bubble-slideshow-jquery-css/) with my Drupal 7 site. The plugin requires Jquery 1.6.2 (Drupal 7 only comes with 1.4.4).

There are some solutions on the net but none seem to work:

- [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update): It only updates jQuery to 1.5. There is a [sandbox](http://drupalcode.org/project/jquery_update.git/commit/ce5b379) version that will update it to jQuery 1.8, but its too complicated to use.
- [jQuery Multi](http://drupal.org/project/jqmulti): I have installed 1.6.2 using this module; however, my site still loads the default jQuery 1.4.4. Version 1.6.2 does not seem to load.
- [Using Newer Versions of jQuery](http://drupal.org/node/1058168): This is a technique for loading multiple jQuery in Drupal 6. Although it works in Drupal 7, my Bubble plugin wont run.

My site is only a simple 1 page webform, so I would be happy if I could supress the default 1.4.4 and then just link to 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is [a patch](http://drupal.org/node/1386294) for the jQuery Update module to update it to jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Have you tried this patch?  Does it break any admin functions?  That is a common problem with jQuery updates for Drupal.

Comment: @MPD I haven't had the opportunity to check out this patch yet.

Comment: The patch is quite hard to apply, as it has to patch multiple files. Is there are ready made version available? Thanks!

Comment: @big_smile Install the dev version of jQuery Update, it has the option to use v1.7, no patches needed. I've used it (albeit in test environments) without any problems so far

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Multi](http://drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module, which you mention in your question, uses jQuery's noConflict() mode. If you installed jQuery Multi and jQuery didn't load, it's likely that you didn't specify any files to load with the new version of jQuery. If you don't specify and files or libraries using the UI or provided hooks, jQuery won't be loaded by default. There is a setting in the configuration form to load jQuery even if no files are targeted to use it.

To use jQuery 1.6.2 with your script, you have to write code to target that file, or put it as a library in the sites/all/libraries folder and select it in the jQuery Multi UI.

If this still doesn't work, try posting an issue in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/jqmulti?categories=All)!